# Creating new spanish words by adding dimunitives

Tags: diminutivos

Please help me out, I am not sure about this. Can you add diminutives to Spanish words where this is not traditionally done and create new words that most people would understand? e.g. take a random word - invitacíon. Could you say invitacíoncitas (or invitacíonitas, I think it sounds better, is the "cita after an n" rule strict?) to mean "little invitations"/pequeñas invitacíones? Do native Spanish speakers understand, and more importantly, appreciate "invented" words such as these? Please note that I am referring to an informal written context here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you would be understood. However, in most places it would be regarded as baby-speak or informal.

Also, you need to bear in mind that the choice of suffix to construct a diminutive varies from region to region.

In Leon, north-west Spain, the suffices "-in" (dinerín) and "-ina" (galletina) are preferred, and often it's not even regarded as baby-speak.

Other regions such a Aragón, north-east Spain, the suffices "-ico" (dinerico) and "-ica" (galletica) are preferred.

In my experience, in Spain the most neutral choice of suffices is "-ito" (dinerito) and "-ita" (galletita).

As pointed out by pHonda, another possibility are the suffices "-illo" (dinerillo) and "-illa" (galletilla). My impression is that these suffices are more common in the south of Spain.

Comment: This answer is quite complete. However, I would add that it would not only be regarded as baby-speak. It is used to add other connotations, depending on the context: 
"Te has ganado unos buenos dinerillos"

Here, `dinerillos` is used to mean that it's not a lot of money, but it doesn't have a childish intention to it.

Comment: @pHonta I can't believe I forgot about "-illo" and "-illa". Thanks. I've now updated the answer.

Comment: I would like to say that there is a link between closed front unrounded vowels and diminutive communication, but I can't find the facts about it anywhere. http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocal_cerrada_anterior_no_redondeada

Comment: @ZaneEdwardDockery You can find the full description [here](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=UemYkhCkNViBSckU) in the RAE's "Nueva gramática de la lengua española (2009)". If nobody else writes an answer with the information in that link, I will consider to  post another answer.

Comment: That only describes what the suffixes do.  It shows no connection between the [i] vowel and diminutives.  I suppose I could post a question about it.  It just seems to me that people use that closed front unrounded vowel to express diminution.  For instance, the [í] in -ísimo not only adds excursiveness but conveys this what I'd call cuteness.

Comment: @ZaneEdwardDockery I thought you were after something like what it's discussed in sections 9.4d. I think formal words like "antiquísimo" may not sound so "cute" as other more common adjectives.

Comment: I completely agree with everything said. As they said, you won't always sound like a baby if you add diminutives but the possibility of sounding like a dork is always there if you add it. So I wouldn't recommend to do it at all unless you have heard the word before!

Comment: I asked my mother-in-law to explain how she makes arroz al horno, and she went: "Cortas unas patatitas en rodajitas finas y las fríes un poquito en aceite. Luego pones a cocer la carne hecha trocitos y, mientras tanto, haces un sofritito con un tomate cortadito..." etc. etc. Some people obviously find it cute to speak using lots of diminutives.